# Hibernate saving to db "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_2n5xttsxwbyc6x67l0x8phfwn'"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have the Recipe.java object with @Entity:

```
...  
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Category> category;  
...
```

Then the Category.java object with @Entity:

```
...  
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private Name name;  
...
```

Let's say that the db looks like this (recipe_category table):

[image]

Then the following code is executed (I just want to add a category to the recipe):

```
...
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findOne(recipeId);
        Category ctg = categoryRepository.findOne(categoryId); // id=1

        List<Category> categories = recipe.getCategory();
        categories.add(ctg);
        recipe.setCategory(categories);

        recipeRepository.save(recipe);
...
```

On the `recipeRepository.save(recipe)` I am getting the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_2n5xttsxwbyc6x67l0x8phfwn'
```

So what would be the solution for this problem?

UPDATE:
 the recipe table structure looks like this:

[image]

The category table structure looks like this:

[image]

So the problem seems to happen because when `recipe.setCategory(categories);` is triggered, it tries to save the `ctg` to the db, but it already exists. What I want is not to save it to db (because is's already there in the 'category' table) but to add a new row in the `recipe_category` table.

Maybe it has to do something with cascade?

Comment: I think it's due to misusage of @OneToMany, this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15802642/7624937

Comment: How do you create your table? Can you post table structure, creation script or at least the definition of the key mentioned in the exception?

Comment: @infiniteRefactor I have updated the question with some details about the tables structure. So the problem is not on the 'creation' process, but when I want to add an existing category to the recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationship is not one-to-many. You want each recipe to have multiple categories. I guess you also want each category to be associated to multiple recipes. This is a many-to-many relationship. You need to use `@ManyToMany` annotation to configure your entities.

Also note that Hibernate relationships are always unidirectional. When you put `@ManyToMany` annotation in `Recipe` class you can access categories associated with a given recipe. In order to access the reverse relationship, to get recipes of a given category you also need to add an appropriate property with `@ManyToMany` annotation to `Category` class too.

I guess you used hbm2ddl or a similar method to auto create your tables and since tables are created for a one-to-many relationship you get an error. More specifically in a unidirectional one-to-many relationship the inverse foreign key column in join table (`category_id` in your `recipe_category` table) has a unique constraint defined on it. Thus with that table schema you cannot associate a category with more then one recipe.

Something like this should work:

```
// Recipe
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="category_map", )
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<> ();
```

and

```
// Category
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="categories")     
private Set<Recipe> recipes;
```

Comment: thank you for your solution and explanation. It works.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue for an hour. Had forgotten that the other relationship is also used by many entities

Answer (score 0):

```
Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findOne(recipeId);
Category ctg = categoryRepository.findOne(categoryId); // id=1

List<Category> categories = recipe.getCategory();
categories.add(ctg);
recipe.setCategory(categories);

recipeRepository.save(recipe);
//categories.clear();
```